# db.sqlite3 file encoding in django

Tags: django, sqlite, pycharm

I am beginner with Django and I'm using PyCharm IDE. I was watching a tutorial following along when I noticed my sqlite file that comes with Django had a question mark next to it (the guy in the video didnt have that). So I clicked it and it prompted me to associate my sqlite file with a certain file type. To experiment I selected the python(.py) file type. Now when I open up I get an error with corrupt code (or at least that's how it looks to me. The error is "File was loaded in the wrong encoding: 'UTF-8.'

When I click on that error message I am able to select from dozens of different encodings.  I'm assuming that's the issue but I don't know for sure. Does anybody have a solution to this issue. Thanks.

I will add two screenshots to clarify what I mean.

[Screenshot 1, list of options if I right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGI1o.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uujS0.png)

Comment: Simply don't try to open a sqlite file as a python file?

Comment: It's a binary file, it doesn't have an encoding. Simply don't try to open it, only work with it using the sqlite3 database interface.

Comment: Django uses its ORM to deal with databases, you never do any coding for the database

Comment: It never stopped functioning, if you mean to stop it being recognised as a python file, search in the settings for `File Types`

Comment: when I click on the python file type under the registered patterns it does show *sqlite3. Is that default or do you think that was me

Comment: Well Sayse, you got me back to where I was yesterday. Is that a problem if my sqlite icon went back to showing a question on it.

Comment: Now I get I'm not supposed to do any coding in that file but at the very least I should be able to open it right?  It just prompts me with sqlite3 is not associated with any file type. please define the association

Comment: Not really, if it bothers you that much just add it to SQL but even that isn't really correct. it just changes the icon, doesn't affect how you use it within your code. I've never clicked on the sqllite file in any of my django projects

Comment: If you want to open it, use the Database Tab and add it as a source or download one of the many sqllite programs

Comment: Okay I'll see how I goes. I appreciate your help. Thank you.